# Nginx is throwing 'no input file specified' when accessing siteb.com/blog

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, configuration

Ive looked at this for hours, but am still not getting where I need  to get to despite doing a lot of hours googling.Nginx is throwing `no input file specified`

my config in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/siteb` looks like:

```
   upstream site {
        #flask app
        server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    }

    upstream siteb-blog {
        #wordpress php
        server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    server {
       server_name siteb.com;
       listen 80;
       root /home/www/flask-deploy/siteb;

       location ~* ^blog/ {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$query_string;
           root /home/www/flask-deploy/siteb-blog;
           location ~ \.php$ {
               fastcgi_pass siteb-blog;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
               include fastcgi_params;
           }
       }

       location / {
            try_files @proxy @proxy;
        }

        location @proxy {
            internal;
            proxy_pass http://siteb;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
        location /static {
            alias  /home/www/flask-deploy/siteb/static/;
        }
    }
```

However, when i try to access `mysite.com/blog` or `mysite.com/blog/info.php` i get a 404 error.

ive checked `error.log` and it doesnt show any errors. `access.log`, just shows:

```
[16/Dec/2016:16:11:56 -0500] "GET /blog/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux armv7l; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
```

My `siteb.com` works fine. `siteb.com/blog` does not.

im specifically trying to get `siteb-blog` working at `siteb.com/blog`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your `location ~* ^blog/ { ... }` regular expression is missing a leading `/`. All `nginx` URIs begin with a leading `/`. Also, if you expect `/blog` to match, you need to remove the trailing `/`.

Comment: @RichardSmith so like `location /blog` ? is that the only thing you see wrong?

Comment: I still get `no input file specified`

Comment: Where is WordPress installed, under `/home/www/flask-deploy/siteb-blog/` or under `/home/www/flask-deploy/siteb-blog/blog/`?

Comment: /home/www/flash deploy/siteb-blog

Answer (score 0):

You have WordPress installed under a directory called `siteb-blog` and would like to access it with a URI prefix of `/blog/`. One of your problems is that the `$request_filename` is constructed from the `root` and URI, so that the `/blog` segment becomes part of the pathname. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

The simple solution with static files is to use the `alias` directive, but I try to avoid using it with `try_files` because of [a long standing bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).

My preferred solution is to silently (using internal rewrite) map the `/blog` URI to `/siteb-blog`, then continue to use `root` as normal.

For example:

```
server {
    server_name siteb.com;
    listen 80;

    location /blog {
        rewrite ^/blog(.*)$ /siteb-blog$1 last;
    }
    location /siteb-blog {
        root /home/www/flask-deploy;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /blog/index.php;

            fastcgi_pass siteb-blog;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://siteb;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    location /static {
        root /home/www/flask-deploy/siteb;
    }
}
```

- You can make the `location /siteb-blog` internal, by adding the `internal` directive. This will make it inaccessible directly.
- A `root` statement in both the `server` block and the `location /static` block is unnecessary - it only needs to appear once.
- The `alias` was unnecessary - `root` is preferred. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.
- The named location was unnecessary - merged with `location /`

Finally, WordPress **needs to know that it is hosted under `/blog`**, otherwise it cannot find its resource files (css & js). You will need to set the values for `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` either using `wp-config.php` or using the WordPress ⇒ DashBoard ⇒ Settings ⇒ General page.